# KendoUI: how to use edit in line for html form in KendoUI

Tags: kendo-ui

Firstly, I am doing a research on KendoUI, and my experience is mainly on struts-layout taglib.
And now I got issues on HTML Form while using KendoUI.

My Questions are as below:

1. Can ***Kendo ListView*** be used to replace ***the html form***? That is, there is no Form any more, but a kendo ListView.
2. If still use **html form**, how to make each field editable in line (is there any kendo widget to do same behavior as JQuery UI plugin **X-editable**)?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing would probably be a Grid that is editable. Clicking on a cell puts it in edit mode: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing

But you could also make a custom Kendo UI widget that behaves basically the same as x-editable by having a clickable element that opens a Kendo Tooltip box with an input element in it.

Comment: thanks CodingWithSpike;  Grid edit mode is not the one I am looking for. In fact, I have to deal with a Form with about 30 columns as input,view,edit; so I am finding kendo widget can handle this form requirement.